# The classification all finite groups which possess a single proper non-trivial normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

We know that

> For $n≥5$, $A_n$ is the *only* proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$.

I am kindly asking to know the possible presented references including the following point, if anybody is aware of them.:

> The classification all finite groups G whose possess a single proper non-trivial normal subgroup.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The cyclic groups of order $p^2$ trivially have this property.

Comment: What you're asking for is essentially one step further than the classification of all finite simple groups.  I doubt much is known past a few examples.  The true answer is probably at least an order of magnitude more complicated then the enormous theorem.

Comment: Sorry for asking, I just see it through $S_n$ and wanted to ask. If it is open I leave it. Thanks @m.k. for opening a door. Extensions. Thanks

Comment: @m.k.: Is it true for infinite groups. I am searching it in Rotman's book but can not find any $G$. I got Alzheimer...

Comment: @m.k. actually, the normal subgroup need not be simple, it is possible to construct examples where it is just characteristically simple (even abelian). I will elaborate with some examples when I am on a proper computer.

Comment: @Tobias: You are right! Sorry, I didn't really think this through..

Comment: As @TobiasKildetoft said, all such groups are (prime) cyclic extensions of characteristically simple groups, and those are just direct products of (the same) simple group.

Comment: @Jim: You are right in saying that this is orders of magnitudes more difficult that classifying finite simple groups. The types of examples are described in Andreas Caranti's post. You could regard most of these as fully classified, but the exception is groups in which the unique normal subgroup is a noncentral elementary abelian $p$-group, and the quotient group is a nonabelian simple group. Classifying these is equivalent to describing all irreducible representations of all finite simple groups in all characteristics (and also the associated second cohomology groups).

Comment: @BabakS.: You don't need to apologize for asking the question.  I upvoted it because I think it's a good one, I just wanted to point out that it's a very hard question and so we shouldn't expect much more then some families of examples.

Comment: Great question! Glad you asked +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get similar examples by taking a [finite, nonabelian simple group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) $S$, and extending it by an outer automorphism of prime order to a group $G$.

Somewhat dually, you can take a quotient $P$ of prime order of the Schur multiplier of $S$, and extend $P$ by $S$ to a group $G$.

Another class of soluble examples can be obtained by starting with two distinct primes $p, q$. Consider the period $n$ of $p$ modulo $q$. Then in the multiplicative  finite field $\mathbf{F}_{p^{n}}$ there is a subgroup $Q$ of order $q$ that acts irreducibly on the additive group $P$ of $\mathbf{F}_{p^{n}}$. The semidirect product $G = PQ$ will have the property, with $P$ the only nontrivial, proper normal subgroup.

Coming back to insoluble examples, one can take a direct power $S^{p}$ of a nonabelian, finite simple group $S$, with $p$ prime. If you let a cyclic group $C_p$ of order $p$ permute cyclically the factors in $S^{p}$, you should get another example, with $S^{p}$ as the distinguished normal subgroup.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I could construct such that group.

Comment: Interestingly (at least to me), the example with the two distinct primes gives precisely those finite groups whose order is not a power of a prime, but such that the order of any proper subgroup is a power of a prime.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I am very thankful if you make me the group touchable. Thanks both of you, Andreas and you.

Comment: @BabakS. I am not sure what you mean by touchable.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Sorry for my bad English. I wanted to have one of that groups. Any way, Thanks.

Comment: @BabakS. A very concrete set of examples are the dihedral groups of odd prime degree (so of order $2p$ for an odd prime $p$).